# What is the ID number on this old Paraguayan ID card and does it matter for ESTA?

Tags: usa, esta, applications, identity-cards, paraguay

I'm submitting my ESTA application and I have dual citizenship (Italian/Paraguayan due to *jus soli*). In order to submit my ESTA the application asks whether I was *ever* given any passport/ID card from some other country.

The answer is: yes, I was given a national ID card in Paraguay when I was a few months old.

I have 2 problems with this:

1. does it really matter? It has expired about 15 years ago. Yet customs seems to care of activities/status of people decades before, so I'd like to lean on the safe side and declare my other document
2. I have no idea *which* is my card number on this card.

   This is the front of the card:

   [image: image of the front of the ID card showing a threating face of a baby, the fingerprint of this ominous individual and the number 3,264,519]

   And this is the back:

   [image: image of the back of the card showing the number 018 - 200192 - 135]

   I can't tell whether the ID card number is `3,264,519` or `018 - 200192 - 135`

Is anyone familiar with this particular document? My guess would be that the number is the one on the front of the card, but I don't want to make a mistake.

Comment: "Ever" means... well... ever.  So to me, that means things 90 years ago count, let alone 15.  People's individual subjectivity would make things too ambiguous if we let them decide what was important and what wasn't.  Chances are the US won't care about this, but you should absolutely disclose it.

Comment: Why don't use ask the Paraguayan consulate in  Italy (or the country which you're currently residing in?) They'll know what the two number represent.

Comment: @CSM consulates are often a lot less helpful than Travel.SE is :)

Answer (score 3):

I sent an email to the Embassy in Rome with the pictures of the ID card and they replied saying that the number is, as I thought, the one in the front of the card: `3264519`.